# Android MaterialBetterSpinner change event

Tags: java, android

Im wondering, if I can set the event listener for a MaterialBetterSpinner when the selected item changes?

Something like that:

```
String [] TIPLIST = "Elektro","Oprema","Vodovod","Ogrevanje","Internet","Požarne naprave","Drugo"};
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterTip = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,TIPLIST);
MaterialBetterSpinner tipSpinner = (MaterialBetterSpinner)findViewById(spinnerTipNapake);
        tipSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapterTip);

tipSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
//MaterialBetterSpinner changed
}
```

But it seems that MaterialBetterSpinner do not have setOnItemSelectedListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MaterialBetterSpinner do not have setOnItemSelectedListener.
Instead you can use this:

```
 tipSpinner.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            spinnerValue=tipSpinner.getText().toString();
              Log.i("value", spinnerValue);

        }
    });
```